# Keeping Images Centered using CSS

Tags: html, css, image, center

I'm writing a small web page for a class assignment. I want to keep the text inside a column and in between paragraphs I'm planning on placing images. How do I keep the images inside the column without specifically changing their dimensions?

CSS

```
body {
        background-image:url("Some Image");
        background-size:cover;
        background-repeat:none;
    }

    .body-box {
                display:block;
                margin-left:33%;
                margin-right:33%;
                padding-left:3%; 
                padding-right:3%;
                border-left:4px solid black;  
                border-right:4px solid black;

                word-wrap:break-word; 
                text-align:justify;
                font-family:'Lato:300',serif; 

                color:black;
                background-color:white; 
            }
```

HTML

```
<div class="body-box">  

        <h1>Some Text</h1>

        <a href="Some Image"><img src="Some Link" 
        alt="Something Vague" width="auto" height="auto" align="center"></a>

        <h2>Some Text</h2>
        <p>Some Paragraph</p>
```

Comment: Now ok with you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532568/keeping-images-centered-using-css/19532714#19532714 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can arrange all image center in your site means,

```
img{
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

If you only one ( this ) image means,

```
.image1 img{
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qKEr8/).

If you need re-size means,

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qKEr8/1/)

re-size and fill the div means,

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qKEr8/1/)

Comment: I'm having the same problem as the example. The images are spilling past the border and I would like them to re-size themselves and stay within the border.

Comment: then give fixed width/height size for image or give in `%`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by defining css for your images like this

```
img
{
width:100%;
height:100%
}
```

By defining this you are telling the image to have its dimension not exceed the height/width of the parent container element

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/Nb9tq/)

[Orignal Image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Wiktionary_small.svg/350px-Wiktionary_small.svg.png)

Comment: I think that works because the image had a 1:1 aspect ratio, mine became distorted. I would like to keep my images as close to their original aspect ratio as possible while still remaining inside the block.

Answer (score 1):

Just give the image a Width and Height of `100%` instead of `auto`

http://jsfiddle.net/XRTba/

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as;

```
 .body-box img {
     display:block;
     margin:0 auto;
 }
```

This centers the images. Do you mean something different?

See this **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ybQBR/)**